# CSS li a 'cursor:pointer' not working in div

Tags: html, css

Within a small `<div>` container that sits within a larger container, I want to put `<a>` links in the form of `<li>` tags.  When I put `cursor:pointer` within my CSS, the hover state does not display a hand and my links are not enabled.

CSS

```
.black_box_contain li{
    font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-left:5px;
    font:inherit;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:5px;
    padding:0.2em;
    display:inline-block; /* This will reduce space */
    cursor:pointer;
}

.black_box_contain li a {
    color:#0144A7;
    font-size:14px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="black_box_contain">North NJ Restaurants <br><br><p>Here are some of my favorite dishes. Hope you enjoy making and eating them as much as I did because they're really good!!</p> <br>
    <li> Italian </li> <br>
    <li> <a> French </a></li><br>
    <li> <a> Mexican </a></li><br>
    <li> <a> Indian </a></li><br>
    <li> <a> Chinese </a></li><br>
    <li> <a> Japanese </a></li><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Cursor Works fine forme Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/8ZP4Q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/CL6HZ/1/

```
<ul>
    <li> Italian </li> <br>
    <li> <a href="#"> French </a></li><br>
    <li> <a href="#"> Mexican </a></li><br>
    <li> <a href="#"> Indian </a></li><br>
    <li> <a href="#"> Chinese </a></li><br>
    <li> <a href="#"> Japanese </a></li><br>
</ul>
```

I added `<ul></ul>` tags, and a `href` for your `a` tags.

`<ul></ul>` or `<ol></ol>` tags are required for `<li></li>` tags.

The most important part of the `<a></a>` tags is the `href`, so if you don't know what your link will be yet, at least add the `href="#"` as a placeholder.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  The problem was this particular div was sitting within another div that was overriding the CSS.  Works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

**Add "href" attribute to all your anchor tags.**

E.g. `<a href="#">click</a>`

Thanks